# ExtJs Date Picker display problem 3.1.0 with Ext.form.DateField

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-architect

I am new to ExtJs and have issues with the display of the date picker.
The actual date picker functionality works, but first 2 columns overlaps as per picture attached.

I have added a date picker to a new Ext.FormPanel() and added panel to a window using ExtJs 3.1.0 as per code below:

```
function save(data) {
    var weekDay = [
                ['1', 'Sunday'],
                ['2', 'Monday'],
                ['3', 'Tuesday'],
                ['4', 'Wednesday'],
                ['5', 'Thursday'],
                ['6', 'Friday'],
                ['6', 'Saturday']
               ];

    var panel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 125,
        frame:true,
        autoHeight   : true,
        title: 'Create',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 450,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        defaults: {width: 200},
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
           new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                 fieldLabel: 'Day of the Week (Optional)',
                 id: 'sDay',
                 store: weekDay,
                 typeAhead: true,
                 allowBlank: true,
                 editable: false,
                 selectOnFocus:true,
                 triggerAction: 'all',
                 emptyText:''
             }),
             new Ext.form.DateField({
                 fieldLabel: 'Date',
                 id: 'sDate',
                 format: 'd/m/Y',
                 allowBlank: true,
                 editable: false,
                 minValue: new Date(),
                 emptyText:'',
                 width: 300,
                 style: 'float: left',
                 cls: 'x-border-box, x-border-box',
                 padding: 5,
                 layout: 'form'
            })
        ],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function() {
                // do stuff
                  win.close();
                }

            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function() {
                win.close();
            }
        }]
    });

    var win = new Ext.Window({
            title      : 'Save stuff',
            width      : 550,
            autoHeight : true,
            modal      : true,
            border     : false,
            layout     : 'fit',
            items      : panel
        });

        win.show();
}
```

[image]

I have tried other date format, increased the width, added cls etc
But, no luck.
Please, has anyone experienced this issue with ExtJs?

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug in 'sencha.fiddle.com'. May you provide some fiddle sample?

Comment: Thanks Arthur. It appears this is a bug is in the existing application. I found out that existing date pickers are also a bit ugly. I will re-visit at a later point. Again, I appreciate your time and effort.